# Let $E$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}^{n}$. Then $E$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\textbf{R}^{n},d)$ be a Euclidean space with either the Euclidean metric, the taxicab metric, or the sup norm metric. Let $E$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}^{n}$. Then $E$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since such metrics are equivalent, it suffices to consider one of them.

Once every compact set is closed and bounded within a metric space, we have only to prove the converse implication.

Since $E\subseteq\textbf{R}^{n}$ is bounded, we conclude that $E\subseteq B(0,r)$ for some $r > 0$. More precisely,
\begin{align*}
|x^{(k)}_{j}| \leq |x^{(k)}_{1}| + |x^{(k)}_{2}| + \ldots + |x^{(k)}_{n}| < r
\end{align*}

In particular, for any sequence $(x^{(k)})_{k=m}^{\infty}\in E$, we conclude each coordinate sequence $(x^{(k)}_{j})_{k=m}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

Therefore, according to the theorem of Bolzano-Weierstrass, each sequence $(x^{(k)}_{j})_{k=m}^{\infty}$ admits a subsequence  which converges to $x_{j}$.

Once a sequence converges iff each coordinate converges, $(x^{(k)})_{k=m}^{\infty}$ has a subsequence which converges to $x = (x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$.

But $E$ is also closed. This means that any sequence of points $x_{k}\in E$ which converges to $x$ implies that $x\in E$.

Gathering all these results, we conclude that if $E$ closed and bounded, then every sequence $x_{n}\in E$ admits a convergent subsequence.

That is to say, $E$ is compact, and we are done.

Could someone critique my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one problem in your solution. You can't just pick a random convergent subsequence of $(x_j^{(k)})$ for every $j$. That way you will get $n$ subsequences which have nothing to do with each other, the indexes might be different. What are the indexes of the subsequence of $(x^{(k)})$ then?

Let's assume $n=2$ to make the writing less complicated, the same proof works for every $n$. What you need to do is the following: first pick a convergent subsequence of $(x_1^{(k)})$, let's call it $(x_1^{(k_j)})_{j=1}^\infty$, and let's call the limit $x_1$. Next, look at the sequence $(x_2^{(k_j)})_{j=1}^\infty$. It has a convergent subsequence $(x_2^{(k_{j_L})})_{L=1}^\infty$ which converges to some $x_2$. Now, since a subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit we also have $(x_1^{(k_{j_L})})\to x_1$ when $L\to\infty$. And now we can indeed say that:

$(x_1^{(k_{j_L})}, x_2^{(k_{j_L})})\to (x_1,x_2)$ as $L\to\infty$.

So now $(x^{(k_{j_L})})_{L=1}^\infty$ is indeed a convergent subsequence of $(x^{(k)})$.

Comment: Many thanks for the contribution @Mark. It has helped to grasp the details.